# Mocking database calls from external class

Tags: java, spring, maven, testing, mocking

There is a library built by our company that is used as an external dependency by the other project we're currently creating tests for (Component Tests, to be more precise). Our goal is thus to let the code flow as deep as possible in all the classes of the `pom.xml` dependencies, but without requiring network calls.

We want to mock all external dependencies, and do not want to have to modify or fork those libraries from our company.

That library makes calls to an Oracle database using a JNDI connection.

The project runs on Tomcat, and the `context.xml` sets up the JNDI connection. We initially wanted to simply inject a H2 connection in there instead, but H2 isn't directly compatible with Oracle and the amount of work to achieve that is too big. There is a stored procedure that would need to be translated into a Java function (for the needs of H2 compatibility), among other things.

Is it possible to somehow intercept the calls made to the database, and return something we'd decide instead?

Solutions we're looking into, but haven't yet understood how to make it work:

1. Something similar to how MockServer/WireMock work.
2. Figuring out how to set up a proxy.
3. Somehow injecting a different class than the one that actually calls the database.

We use Java 8, Spring 5 with XML configuration of beans, and Maven Cargo to start the Tomcat 8. The library uses Java 8, Spring 4, and the classes establishing connections to the database are not Beans.

**EDIT**:

More context on our testing set up.

The project has 2 modules: one for the service itself (it contains the SOAP endpoints), and one for the component-tests.

The `service` one isn't started with a `public static void main` (i.e. not even through Spring Boot context launcher).

The `test` one starts the test suite through a `TestNg` class that launches the `Cucumber` runner.

Thus, to test the service, we trigger a Maven Cargo to build the `service` and deploy in an embedded Tomcat, injecting our test-specific `context.xml` file. Then, subsequently we launch the CucumberRunner which itself ends up calling the endpoints for the tests.

Comment: Do you have access to the class that calls the database class?

Comment: @MubarakaBharucha Access in what sense? We have access to the GitHub repository itself, and we can see the class in IntelliJ's external dependency of the project by opening the `jar` file.

Comment: Did you look into PowerMock?

Comment: @MubarakaBharucha I've heard of it as being a superset of Mockito, but I haven't really used those tools that much. I've edited the OP with more context on how we run the tests. My understanding would be that I should be able to set up PowerMock on the deployed `service`, rather than on the `test` module, and I'm not sure how I'd do that.

Comment: You should be able to setup PowerMock on test module as well. Seems like you're using Cucumber which is an alternative of Powermock, so it should be able to mock the database connection as well. I'm not familiar with Cucumber so can't help you with that.

Comment: @MubarakaBharucha I don't think it'd work. Maybe I'm not understanding properly. A Cucumber test would set up a request, then send that request to the Tomcat server, and then make assertions on the response. I do not want to mock the call to Tomcat because it'd defeat the purpose of testing the service. I'd want to mock the call to a certain class within the Tomcat server, instead, but I'm not sure how I'd do that considering I use Maven Cargo to launch Tomcat.